# How to find the difference between collections(arrays) of JQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to perform something like this:

```
var elems = $('.lots-of-elements')
```

Then AJAX response and again:

```
var moreElems = $('.lots-of-elements')
```

And I need to find only new ones with something like this:

```
var newElems = array_diff(elems, moreElems)
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: If you just loaded more with an ajax request, surely you already know which ones are new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

```
var elems = $('.lots-of-elements')
var moreElems = $('.lots-of-elements');
var newElems = moreElems.not( elems );
```

Comment: Only it should be $(moreElems.not( elems ))

Comment: How so? `.not(..)` returns a jQuery collection?